# Motherboard causes Windows boot into INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE

Tags: windows-10, boot, hardware-detection

Alternative problem:
After replacing motherboard(MB) or resetting BIOS settings to defaults, Windows boots into INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE (IBD)

There are tons of IBD questions, but they are mostly about noticeable failures of software or hardware. In this case, no software or hardware malfunction is expected, but BSOD happens.

Main symptoms, while using same disk with W10:

On the previous PC/MB (or other hardware):

- Boot from SATA works well

On the new specific Gigabyte PC/MB:

- SATA boot: ends with IBD BSOD
- USB (SATA to USB direct adapter) boot: OK
- When trying to install W10, SSD or M.2 are not detected (unless drivers are manually provided?)
- Boot with Live USB (Clonezilla or Linux Lite): detects M.2 and SATA disks correctly

How to fix W10 boot BSOD?

Comment: Please give details about the motherboard, BIOS and disk.

Comment: Already ensured that this occurs on multiple MB's of different manufacturers, narrowing down to just one will be a bit misleading. And on multiple BIOS versions, except defaults were fixed at some point. The most important symptom is actually that no soft/hard failures are expected.

Comment: Normally this then would be caused by some software that you install. Have you tried to install a vanilla Windows 10?

Comment: Honestly, what caused this is tricky, especially after updating BIOS. It was possible to repair boot and to boot without VMD in the end - details are in the answer below. Excuse me for keeping this Q/A imperfect and unfinished, but specifically enabling VMD can be a lifesaver for someone who just needs to boot now and solve details later. So I'd like to keep Q/A for now as is, to check if it will help anyone.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try enabling **VMD Controller in BIOS**.
   In my case, it was disabled in the default BIOS preset, and enabling made startup possible.
   Updating BIOS version changed the defaults to VMD enabled though, so update + reset was an alternative solution here.
2. It is not clear if this part is necessary at all, but could've been part of the solution. Boot from direct SATA-USB adapter on new hardware and **ensure/install drivers for undetected devices**.
   Possibly after this step, boot via internal SATA was fluent (yet not with VMD disabled).
   If you don't have direct SATA-USB adapter, there is a chance that disassembling some external USB HDD will loot one.
   Possibly this approach will work for M.2-USB adapter as well.
   Worth a note, that solutions to prepare windows via just registry editing won't work here because specific drivers are required. They are not available via Windows update, and are supposed to be downloaded/installed manually from folder. This is not standard installation, but an attempt to run a system from other MB without reinstalling. Live system approach is much easier than trying to guess randomly which driver will actually work after hardware replace.
3. On the very first attempt, boot to Safe mode still ended with IBD, so the assumption was that the case is not trivial. After 1), 2) and full backup with Clonezilla, I tried to run standard W10 Startup Repair, and after that boot in Safe mode actually worked. Disabled VMD at some point during 3. and startup proceeded correctly.